# why filewriter not working in java?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, java-io, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I using `FileReader` to read and `FileWriter` to a file. I am seeing that reading is successful (by printing to `console`) but writing does not happen.

here is the code:

```
public class ReadingIO {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            processfile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void  processfile() throws IOException{
        BufferedReader fi = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words.txt"));
        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("testwrite.txt"));
        String b;
        while ((b=fi.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(b);
            out.write(b);

        }
    }


}
```

If I use `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` it works. I want to know why FileWriter fails, not alternative ways to accomplish this.

Comment: flush or close your stream.

Comment: I did not close `FileOutputStream` and it worked. but with `FileReader` it fails

Answer (score 2):

You need to call **flush()** while using `Writer`.

But not needed while `FileOutputStream`

Close calls flush on the stream, so flush is not needed if you want to close the stream.

Comment: but I did not close FileOutputStream and it still worked, why is that?

Comment: because `FileOutputStream` is not buffered, so the data is directly written to the file.

Comment: there is a close method for FileOutputStream too. why is it only for bufferedStream is closing essential?

Comment: @user1988876 Closing is *essential* for *all* streams. However as FileOutputStream isn't buffered, everything you wrote went to the file. If you don't close or flush a buffered stream/writer, you will lose data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `out.flush()` when you are done.

Comment: Also  `fi.close()` and `out.close()`

Comment: not also, just use the `.close()` methods, they implicitly call `.flush()` and it's less to remember/mess up.

Answer (score 1):

Add following lines after while loop.

```
out.close();
```

This method will cal flush() method automatically to write data to file which is still buffered, then close the stream.

Comment: The flush() is redundant. Closing the stream flushes it.

Comment: The idea is that you amend your answer.